# Error during Negotiation Request Android SignalR 2.2.0

Tags: javascript, android, signalr

I am connecting to the SignalR server from the Javascipt client, which is located on the Android device.

If the Page is hosted in other server and I open the html page in the android browser, it works. But if i have my app unzip the MyWebsite.zip file and open the html file having the signalR javascript, I get Error during Negotiation Request.

Am i missing something.

Comment: There is a [SignalR library for Android and Java](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client). Why don't you use it? No need javascript.

Comment: I am using Cordova to create my App. My App has only Javascript files.